# Cannot get current URL in Selenium::Remote::Driver in perl

Tags: selenium, perl

I navigated to google and called the get_current_url() method. but it's showing timeout and exiting the program.

Here is the code  I tried

```
my $driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new(
  'browser_name' => 'firefox',
  'platform'     => 'Windows',
  'extra_capabilities' => {
    'moz:firefoxOptions' => {},
   }
 );
$driver->debug_on() ;
$driver->get("https://www.google.com/");
wait_until {print $driver->get_path()};
$driver->quit;
```

I've turned on debug and got the following output in console

```
Prepping get
Executing get
REQ: POST, http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session/69ced133-9420-4b0e-a7fd-e4f6bb343f7e/url, {"url":"https://www.google.co.in/"}
RES: {"value":null}

Prepping getCurrentUrl
Executing getCurrentUrl
REQ: GET, http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session/69ced133-9420-4b0e-a7fd-e4f6bb343f7e/url, {}
RES: read timeout at C:/Perl64/lib/Net/HTTP/Methods.pm line 268.


Error while executing command: Server returned error message read timeout at C:/Perl64/lib/Net/HTTP/Methods.pm line 268.
 instead of data at C:/Perl64/site/lib/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm line 403.
 at C:/Perl64/site/lib/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm line 353.
Prepping quit
Executing quit
REQ: DELETE, http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session/69ced133-9420-4b0e-a7fd-e4f6bb343f7e, {}
```

In console,program stucks here for while- 'Executing getCurrentURL'  and later shown up with timeout message-Res:read timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me using Windows 10, Strawberry Perl version 5.30.1.

I installed `geckodriver.exe` from

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

and Selenium Server from

https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/

then downloaded `firefox` binary from

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/

and then started the server successfully from the command prompt:

```
> java  "-Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=geckodriver/geckodriver.exe" -jar selenium-server/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -host localhost -port 4444
20:00:48.591 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
20:00:53.896 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$3] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
2020-07-06 20:00:54.601:INFO::main: Logging initialized @12170ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
20:01:05.928 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
20:01:23.567 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444
```

Now the following Perl script works:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;
my $driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new(
    remote_server_addr => "127.0.0.1"
);
$driver->get('http://www.google.com');
say "Result: ", $driver->get_title();
$driver->quit();
```

**Output**:

```
Result: Google
```

Note: using `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` for `remote_server_addr` does not work for some reason, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62762851/2173773) for more information.

Comment: The problem is with the selenium server I downloaded. Now its working fine