# Cannot access selenium server on localhost from Perl using LWP::UserAgent on Windows 10, Strawberry Perl

Tags: selenium, perl

On Windows 10, I installed `geckodriver.exe` from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and
Selenium Server from https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/

I started the server successfully from the command prompt:

```
> java  "-Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=geckodriver/geckodriver.exe" -jar selenium-server/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -host localhost -port 4444
20:00:48.591 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
20:00:53.896 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$3] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
2020-07-06 20:00:54.601:INFO::main: Logging initialized @12170ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
20:01:05.928 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
20:01:23.567 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444
```

I can test that the server is working by visiting the URL http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/status from Chrome web browser. The output is:

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "value": {
    "ready": true,
    "message": "Server is running",
    "build": {
      "revision": "e82be7d358",
      "time": "2018-11-14T08:25:53",
      "version": "3.141.59"
    },
    "os": {
      "arch": "amd64",
      "name": "Windows 10",
      "version": "10.0"
    },
    "java": {
      "version": "14.0.1"
    }
  }
}
```

However, if I try to access the server from Perl using `LWP::UserAgent`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $result=$ua->get("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/status/");
print $result->status_line.".\n";
```

the output is:

```
500 Can't connect to localhost:4444 (Bad address).
```

Comment: IPv4 vs IPv6 issue? Try using `127.0.0.1` and `::1` instead of `localhost`

Comment: Firewall issue (causing Perl to be blocked)?

Comment: @ikegami Thanks! Using: `http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/status/` works fine. Any idea what is the issue?

Comment: Not sure exactly. Part of it will come down to the definition of `localhost`. And as I mentioned, IPv4 vs IPv6 probably play a role. Maybe it was originally trying to reach `::1`. Maybe that would work except that it isn't supported by LWP  (explaining why Chrome works). [To be clear, I don't know if LWP supports IPv6 or not.]